# Modify and Run examples of Apache Ignite

Tags: java, caching, ignite

I want to modify the following test case and then run the binary.

[ignite/examples/src/main/java/org/apache/ignite/examples/datagrid/CachePutGetExample.java](https://github.com/apache/ignite/blob/master/examples/src/main/java/org/apache/ignite/examples/datagrid/CachePutGetExample.java)

How should I do it?

I followed the following instructions:
https://github.com/apache/ignite/tree/master/examples 
However, I could not find how to run binary for the specific class.

Answer (score 1):

Ignite binary build contains `examples` folder which is a separate Maven-based project which you can import into your favorite IDE and then run the example classes from there. You're free to change them, of course.

Standalone server nodes can be started using special `ExampleNodeStartup` class included in the project, or using `ignite.sh` script. Refer to individual example's JavaDoc for specific details.

The build can be downloaded here: https://ignite.apache.org/download.cgi#binaries